# How can I append content to two different Divs using JS?

Tags: javascript

So, playing around with javascript again, I am trying to append JSON content to two enclosing Divs. for some reason, it only appears in the appendChild set last. 
here is the relevant part of the code:

```
const text = document.createElement('div')
counter = 0
data.forEach(element => {
    counter ++
    const dot = document.createElement('div')
    dot.className = 'dot'
    if(counter === 1){
        dot.classList.add('active')
    }
    dot.addEventListener('click',()=>{
        text.textContent = element.content
    })

    document.querySelector('#dots-mobile').appendChild(dot)
    document.querySelector('#dots').appendChild(dot)


});
```

in this case, the content will be appended to #dots. If I switch it around, it will be appended to #dots-mobile

I know I'm not an expert, so any suggestions are welcome :) 
thanks!

Comment: What's `text` in `text.textContent = element.content`? Where is that declared/defined?

Comment: Also a given node (element) can only be the child of one parent. You'll have to create *two* `<div>` nodes.

Comment: added the text const. my Html has two serpeate Div nodes. One: <div class="col-sm-1" id="dots">
        
                </div>
and another seperate one : 
<div class="row justify-content-center " id="dots-mobile">
                
            </div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only have a single `dot` element. Using it as the argument to `appendChild` the second time **moves** it from its first parent to the second.

You'll need to create **two** `dot` elements instead. You can conveniently clone an element via [`cloneNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode), but you'll need to attach the event handlers individually:

```
const text = document.createElement('div')
counter = 0
data.forEach(element => {
    counter ++
    const dot1 = document.createElement('div')
    dot1.className = 'dot'
    if(counter === 1){
        dot1.classList.add('active')
    }
    // *** Create one handler for both elements
    const handler = ()=>{
        text.textContent = element.content
    }
    // *** Use the handler for dot1
    dot1.addEventListener('click', handler)
    // *** Create dot2, use the handler for it as well
    const dot2 = dot1.cloneNode(true)
    dot2.addEventListener('click', handler)

    document.querySelector('#dots-mobile').appendChild(dot1) // *** Use dot1
    document.querySelector('#dots').appendChild(dot2)        // *** Use dot2
});
```

*(I've tried to stick to your coding style there, no `;`, etc.)*

---

Side note: Probably better to use `document.getElementById("id")` than `document.querySelector('#id')` since the latter requires parsing the CSS selector.